# Symfony2 session lost after each request

Tags: php, symfony, session, redis

I run the latest Symfony2 (v2.6.4) on debian(7) wheezy with vagrant&puphpet.

It seems that symfony/php saves the session in redis but creates a new session for each new request.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys PHPREDIS_SESSION:*
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> keys PHPREDIS_SESSION:*
1) "PHPREDIS_SESSION:k16dbk02j15298h9snfd2795m7"
127.0.0.1:6379> keys PHPREDIS_SESSION:*
1) "PHPREDIS_SESSION:k16dbk02j15298h9snfd2795m7"
2) "PHPREDIS_SESSION:bt3ki1of21gjbo39uktj9es7b3"
3) "PHPREDIS_SESSION:lv43uinkb4cn5h7evarl8r0n00"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

This is the result after a couple of refreshes.

In my (/etc/php5/fpm/)php.ini my session settings are

```
session.save_handler=redis
session.save_path="tcp://localhost:6379"
```

And I validated these settings.

---

UPDATE:

I tried to make sessions write to /tmp/php5/sessions and this method also failed.

Directory is nginx and php5-fpm owned under the vagrant user, I can write/read the file from my frontcontroller.

---

UPDATE2:

It appears to be a browser issue (google chrome). I tried another browser (firefox) and it worked.